# Query Activities associated with Contacts

Tags: soql, contact, tasks

I am building a lightning component on Account that takes the Account ID and returns the contacts and the most recent task associated with it.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static list<Contact> getRelatedContactList(Id recordId)
{
        
List<Contact> conList = [Select id,firstname,lastname,Contact_Salutation_First_and_Last_Name__c,(SELECT Id,Subject,OwnerId,ActivityDate,Owner.Name FROM Tasks where Status = 'Completed' ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1) from Contact where AccountId =: recordId and Key_contact__c = true];
return conList;
}
```

The above logic works perfect when the Task is only associated with one contact/Primary contact. It doesnot return back the tasks in which the contact is not primary or If the tasks has multiple contact the above query doesnot return them. I read we can use 'TaskRelation' but I am not sure how to use them in here as I have only the Account ID and not the Tasks ID.

Answer (score 0):

*First principles - don't put your whole SOQL on 1 line - too hard to read/debug*

If you have shared activities enabled, you'll need to query from `Contact` via relationship `TaskRelations` and because `TaskRelation` has a lookup field to the `Task`, you can filter on the `TaskRelation` that has the most recent `Task.LastModifiedDate`

```
return  
    [SELECT Id,Firstname,Lastname,Contact_Salutation_First_and_Last_Name__c,
       (SELECT Task.Id,Task.Subject,Task.OwnerId,Task.ActivityDate,Task.Owner.Name 
          FROM TaskRelations where Task.Status = 'Completed' 
          ORDER BY Task.LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1) 
        FROM Contact where AccountId =: recordId and Key_contact__c = true];
```

Reference [TaskRelation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_taskrelation.htm?search_text=taskrelation)